# If then convex condition in mixed integer linear programming with binary variables

Tags: logic, convex-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have a convex polynomial $f(x_1,\dots,x_t)$ where $x_1,\dots,x_t\in\mathbb R$ and constant $a$.

If condition $$f(x_1,\dots,x_t)\leq a$$ holds I have to make variables $y_1,\dots,y_n\in\mathbb R$ ($n\geq t$ and some of $y_i$s are same as $x_i$s) satisfy some linear condition $Ay\leq b$ where $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb R^{m}$ are fixed and known where $y^T=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ is variable vector.

If condition $$f(x_1,\dots,x_t)> a$$ holds I just have to make variables $y_1,\dots,y_n\in\mathbb R$ to satisfy nothing however it should be defined.

> Is this possible to this with feasibility Mixed integer programming with no objective function possibly by introducing integer variables and only additional linear conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two alternatives, neither of which is perfect. Both involve a binary variable $\delta$, a large scalar $M$ and a vector of large scalars $\vec{M}$. Both use the inequality $Ay\le b + \vec{M}(1-\delta)$.

The first approach adds the inequality $f(x)\ge a - M\delta$. The weakness of this version is that if $f(x)=a$, $\delta$ can be either 1 (logically correct) or 0. So the if-then requirement fails to be enforced if $f(x)=a$.

The second approach instead uses $f(x)\ge a + \epsilon - M\delta$ for some small $\epsilon > 0$. The good news is that $f(x)=a$ will result in $Ay\le b$. The bad news is that $f(x)\in (a, a+\epsilon)$ enforces $Ay\le b$, which was not wanted.

Note that @Kuifje's approach, penalizing $\delta$, can achieve exactly what was asked for, provided that a penalty coefficient can be found that is large enough to enforce the requirement (which is testable: see if the final solution violates it) but not large enough to produce a suboptimal solution (harder to test).

Answer (score 0):

$$
Ay \le b + M(1-\delta) \\
f(x_1,...,x_n) \le a + M(1-\delta) \\
\delta \in \{0,1\}
$$
And penalize the $\delta$ variable in your cost function so that it is set to $0$ only if there is no other option.

Comment: @Kuifke What happens if condition does not hold is also important to me.

Comment: If the condition does not hold, then $\delta = 0$, and the first equation becomes $Ay \le b+M$ which always holds.

Comment: Then $y$ may not satisfy the condition.

Comment: But you wrote that "if the condition does not hold I should not care."

Comment: That means such a $y$ should be definable in the program.

Comment: How to penalize? Sounds vague.

Comment: add $\pm \omega \delta$ to your objective function, where $\omega$ is the penalty value.

Comment: You dont see the point $Ay\leq b+M(1-\delta)$ is a finite region and $y$ outside this is not defined.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. If your variable $y$ is well defined in the first place, it should not be a problem. It will take any value in $\mathbb{R}$. $M$ is a big constant, this way the equation always holds no matter what value $y$ takes. Imagine $M:= \infty$, do you see what happens ?

Comment: Yes $M=\infty$ is only thing that works and no other finite $M$ works and so your approach fails.

Comment: It's just a suggestion, a classical technique used in linear programming. 
Do you have a cost function that depends on $y$? If you do, and if for instance your are minimizing, than it is easy to find a finite $M$ that works.

Comment: If $y$ variables are unconstrained why does their value matter ?

Comment: You dont get it. The program has to be definable for all values of $y$ and for selected values in convex region has to satisfy a constraint. We need to come up with a condition that degenerates to triviality outside the convex region but still keeps $y$ definable. If you do what you say then $y$ becomes undefined in certain regions.

Comment: What precludes $f(x)<a$, $\delta=0$ and $Ay > b$ in this formulation?

Comment: @prubin  the fact that $1-delta$ is penalized in the cost function. How would you do it ?

Comment: Penalizing $1-\delta$ works, but it's tricky: too little penalty and you get the logic error I mentioned; too big a penalty and you force $f(x)\le a$ and $Ay\le b$ even if those would otherwise be suboptimal.

Comment: Thank you for your input and clarifications. Great explanations, as always.